# Vuetify: v-text-field with outlined don't display the border

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I use the Vuetify for Vuejs project. I add v-text-field elements to v-form with outlined property but it don't show the border. Thanks.

- Code add Vuetify to project in main.js:

```
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'
import 'vuetify/src/stylus/app.styl'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
import 'material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css'

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
    iconfont: 'md',
});
```

- Use in the register form:

```
<v-form @submit.prevent="handleRegister" id="register-form" data-vv-scope="register-form">
    <v-text-field outlined v-model="user.email" v-validate="'required|email'"
        name="email" :error-messages="errors.collect('register-form.email')" 
        label="メールアドレス"
        :class="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && errors.has('register-form.email')}">
    </v-text-field>
    <v-text-field v-model="user.password" v-validate="'required|min:8|max:20'"
        :error-messages="errors.collect('register-form.password')"
        :type="'password'" single-line outlined name="password"
        label="パスワード"
        :class="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && errors.has('register-form.password') }"
    ></v-text-field>
    <v-text-field v-model="user.password_confirmation"
         v-validate="'required|min:8|max:20'"
         :error-messages="errors.collect('register-form.password_confirmation')"
         label="パスワード確認" name="password_confirmation"
         single-line outlined :type="'password'"
         :class="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && errors.has('register-form.password_confirmation') }"
    ></v-text-field>
    <v-text-field v-model="user.user_id" v-validate="'required|min:4|max:20'"
         :error-messages="errors.collect('register-form.user_id')"
         single-line outlined label="ユーザID" name="user_id"
         :class="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && errors.has('register-form.user_id') }"
    ></v-text-field>
</v-form>
```

Comment: Do you have any custom css in your component?

Comment: As you can see in this example, this code should work by default https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-gngf5?fontsize=14 I need more info to investigate your problem

Comment: I don't have any custom css. Thanks Dshadrin

Comment: What is your vuetify version?

Comment: i'm use Vuetify 1.5.5. Wait a bit for checking css.

Comment: if i comment line: import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css', v-text-field show border.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use 1.5.5 vuetify version. You should try **outline** attribute instead of **outlined**. They changed it in v 2.0, and i think you've read v2 docs.

Comment: yeah, now it work correctly, thanks so much DShadrin.

Comment: Can you please mark this answer as right, to help people faster find out with similar problems

Comment: is there a way to make the <v-text-input> rounded as in v2?